"UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character error" but probably not because of code or data
I wanted to run GridSearchCV to optimize my emotion recognition from sound project's hyperparameters. This process is too heavy for my old work pc, so I wanted to run this code on my high spec gaming pc. Then I encountered this error after running for a while:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Toker\Desktop\Model_optimization\main.py", line 142, in <module>
    lstm_auto_opt_training(train_df)
  File "c:\Users\Toker\Desktop\Model_optimization\main.py", line 94, in lstm_auto_opt_training
    grid_result = grid.fit(x, y)
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Toker\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py", line 1474, in wrapper
    return fit_method(estimator, *args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Toker\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_search.py", line 970, in fit
    self._run_search(evaluate_candidates)
  File "C:\Users\Toker\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_search.py", line 1527, in _run_search
    evaluate_candidates(ParameterGrid(self.param_grid))
  File "C:\Users\Toker\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_search.py", line 947, in evaluate_candidates
    _warn_or_raise_about_fit_failures(out, self.error_score)
  File "C:\Users\Toker\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_validation.py", line 536, in _warn_or_raise_about_fit_failures
    raise ValueError(all_fits_failed_message)
ValueError: 
All the 1296 fits failed.
It is very likely that your model is misconfigured.
You can try to debug the error by setting error_score='raise'.

Below are more details about the failures:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
864 fits failed with the following error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Toker\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_validation.py", line 895, in _fit_and_score
    estimator.fit(X_train, y_train, **fit_params)
  File "C:\Users\Toker\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\scikeras\wrappers.py", line 1501, in fit
    super().fit(X=X, y=y, sample_weight=sample_weight, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Toker\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\scikeras\wrappers.py", line 770, in fit
    self._fit(
  File "C:\Users\Toker\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\scikeras\wrappers.py", line 938, in _fit
    self._fit_keras_model(
  File "C:\Users\Toker\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\scikeras\wrappers.py", line 535, in _fit_keras_model
    hist = self.model_.fit(x=X, y=y, **fit_args)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Toker\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 122, in error_handler
    raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
  File "C:\Users\Toker\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 21-40: character maps to <undefined>

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
432 fits failed with the following error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Toker\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_validation.py", line 895, in _fit_and_score
    estimator.fit(X_train, y_train, **fit_params)
  File "C:\Users\Toker\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\scikeras\wrappers.py", line 1501, in fit
    super().fit(X=X, y=y, sample_weight=sample_weight, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Toker\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\scikeras\wrappers.py", line 770, in fit
    self._fit(
  File "C:\Users\Toker\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\scikeras\wrappers.py", line 938, in _fit
    self._fit_keras_model(
  File "C:\Users\Toker\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\scikeras\wrappers.py", line 535, in _fit_keras_model
    hist = self.model_.fit(x=X, y=y, **fit_args)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Toker\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 122, in error_handler
    raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
  File "C:\Users\Toker\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u2501' in position 21: character maps to <undefined>

I also get this kind of messages which never happened in old pc:
enter image description here
This code works perfectly fine on my old pc, there is no problem on code or data. Can anyone help me with this? Thanks in advance.
here's my code:
import math
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import librosa
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder, OneHotEncoder
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split, GridSearchCV
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import LSTM, Dense, Dropout
from scikeras.wrappers import KerasClassifier 
from tensorflow.keras.constraints import max_norm

#Extracts the sound features
def extract_sound_feature(audio_file, max_length=100, n_mfcc=20, n_fft=512):
    dur = len(audio_file)
    audio, sr=librosa.load(audio_file, duration=math.floor(float(dur)), offset=0.5)
    mfcc = librosa.feature.mfcc(y=audio, sr=sr, n_mfcc=n_mfcc, n_fft=n_fft)
    mfcc_mean = np.mean(mfcc, axis=1)
    return mfcc_mean


#Importing sound files
def import_sound_files(table_df, sound_df, folder_name):
    for i in range(len(table_df)):
       try:
          file_name = f"{folder_name}/{table_df['fileName'][i]}.wav"
          features = extract_sound_feature(file_name, 150, 20, 512)
        # Add the remaining code inside the try block
       except Exception as e:
          print(f"Error occurred at index {i}: {e}")

       temp_df=pd.DataFrame({
           'fileName': [table_df['fileName'][i]],
           'soundFile': [features]
           }) 
       sound_df=pd.concat([sound_df, temp_df], ignore_index=True)
    return sound_df


def lstm_training_preprocess(table_df):
    le_x = LabelEncoder()
    enc_y = OneHotEncoder()
    table_df['Sentiment'] = le_x.fit_transform(table_df['Sentiment']).astype(float)

    #Adding "Sentiment" and "soundFile" column together
    table_df['soundFile'] = np.array(table_df['soundFile'])
    for i in range(len(table_df['soundFile'])):
        table_df['soundFile'][i] = np.append(table_df['soundFile'][i], table_df['Sentiment'][i])
    
    x=table_df['soundFile']
    y=enc_y.fit_transform(table_df[['Emotion']])

    x = [i for i in x]
    x = np.array(x)
    x = np.expand_dims(x, -1)
    y = y.toarray()

    return x,y

def define_model(neurons=10, dropout_rate=0.0, weight_constraints=0, optimizers='Adam'):
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(LSTM(neurons, return_sequences=False, kernel_initializer= 'he_uniform',
                   input_shape=(21,1), kernel_constraint=max_norm(weight_constraints)))
    model.add(Dropout(dropout_rate))
    model.add(Dense(neurons, kernel_initializer='he_uniform', activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dropout(dropout_rate))
    model.add(Dense(7, kernel_initializer='he_uniform', activation='softmax'))

    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
                  optimizer=optimizers,
                  metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model


# Auto hyperparameter tuning
def lstm_auto_opt_training(train_df):
    x, y= lstm_training_preprocess(train_df)
    x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test= train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.2)

    model=KerasClassifier(build_fn=define_model, verbose=1)
    model__dropout_rate = [0.2, 0.4]
    model__weight_constraints = [1, 2, 3]
    model__neurons = [64, 128, 256]
    model__optimizers = ['SGD', 'Nadam', 'SGD', 'RMSprop']
    #activation = ['relu', 'tanh', 'sigmoid']
    batch_size=[128, 256, 512]
    epochs = [75, 89]

    #neurons, dropout_rate, weight_constraints, optimizer, activation
    param_grid = dict(model__neurons=model__neurons, model__dropout_rate=model__dropout_rate, 
                      model__weight_constraints=model__weight_constraints, model__optimizers=model__optimizers,
                      batch_size=batch_size, epochs=epochs)
    
    grid = GridSearchCV(estimator=model, param_grid=param_grid, n_jobs=6, cv=3)
    grid_result = grid.fit(x, y)

    print("Best: %f using %s" % (grid_result.best_score_, grid_result.best_params_))
    means = grid_result.cv_results_['mean_test_score']
    stds = grid_result.cv_results_['std_test_score']
    params = grid_result.cv_results_['params']
    for mean, stdev, param in zip(means, stds, params):
        print("Mean = %f (std=%f) with %r" % (mean,stdev, param))

    print("Finished")


def create_dataframe(temp_df):
    table_df=pd.DataFrame(columns=['fileName','Emotion','Content','Sentiment'])

    for i in range(len(temp_df)): 
          new_fileName=temp_df.loc[i]['fileName']
          new_Emotion=temp_df.loc[i]['Emotion']
          new_Sentiment=temp_df.loc[i]['Sentiment']
          new_Content=temp_df.loc[i]["Utterance"].lower()

          new_line=pd.DataFrame({
             'fileName': [new_fileName],
             'Emotion': [new_Emotion],
             'Content': [new_Content],
             'Sentiment': [new_Sentiment]
          })

          table_df=pd.concat([table_df,new_line], ignore_index=True)

    return table_df


def dataframe_preprocessing(data_folder, unprocessed_df):
    sound_df=pd.DataFrame(columns=['fileName', 'soundFile'])
    document_df=pd.DataFrame(columns=['fileName','Emotion','Content','Sentiment'])
    document_df=create_dataframe(unprocessed_df)
    unprocessed_df.drop(unprocessed_df.index, inplace=True)

    sound_df=import_sound_files(document_df, sound_df, data_folder)
    document_df=pd.concat([document_df, sound_df], axis=1, join='outer')
    sound_df.drop(sound_df.index, inplace=True)
    return document_df

train_data_folder = "training"
unprocessed_train_df=pd.read_excel('train_excel.xlsx')
train_df=pd.DataFrame(columns=['fileName','Emotion','Content','Sentiment'])
train_df=dataframe_preprocessing(train_data_folder, unprocessed_train_df)
lstm_auto_opt_training(train_df)


